# Stripe Bitcoin Support for Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Curious if anyone knows how we would setup Bitcoin support for Craft Commerce.

We know how to handle it on the user and Stripe site to enable the checkout but will we need a custom payment handler on the PHP side to handle the responses or will the built in Stripe support work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily Craft Commerce per se, but you could use Charge 2 to integrate with Stripe with Craft. In Charge 2, configuring Stripe Checkout to use Bitcoin is trivial, but could also be made to work with Stripe.js, which is where the deep integration with Craft CMS comes into play.